# WP Custom Comment Callback Not Responding

Tags: functions, comments

I have a client site that has requested a custom comment format for posts of a specific category.

In my loop template, I have this:

```
<div id="gallery-commentlist">
     <ul class="gallery-commentlist">
          <?php wp_list_comments( 'type=comment&callback=gallery_comment'); ?>
     </ul>
</div><!-- #gallery-commentlist -->
```

And in my functions.php file, I have this:

```
<?php function gallery_comment($comment, $args, $depth) {
   $GLOBALS['comment'] = $comment; ?>
   <li <?php comment_class(); ?> id="li-comment-<?php comment_ID() ?>">
     <div id="comment-<?php comment_ID(); ?>">
        <div class="gallery-comment-body">
            <p><span class="gallery-comment-author"><?php comment_text() ?>:</span> <?php comment_text() ?></p>
        </div>
        <div class="comment-meta commentmetadata"><a href="<?php echo esc_url( get_comment_link( $comment->comment_ID ) ) ?>"> &ndash; 
        <?php get_comment_date() ?> at <?php get_comment_time() ?></a><?php edit_comment_link(__('(Edit)'),'  ','') ?>
        </div>
    </div>
<?php }?>
```

It's not returning any comments, but for the life of me, I can't figure out why. I followed the instructions in the WP codex to the letter. Is there something that I have overlooked?

Thanks for any help!

ty

Comment: Does it function correctly without the callback argument i.e. `wp_list_comments( 'type=comment' )` ?

Comment: No, it doesn't. What does that mean?

Comment: Glad to see you've solved it. I asked since it would rule out if your custom callback was at fault.

Comment: Thanks for the help. I should have thought of the solution sooner, since I recently struggled with setting up a custom query to override wp_query. It didn't occur to me that it would do the same thing with comments. I thought it behaved more like a straight up template placement. Live and learn.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is apparently some sort of query call that takes place as part of the `comments_template()` call, just as there is with loop calls.

When I put my custom function in the comments template, it works perfectly.

I tried putting the entire contents of the comments template into my custom loop-single template, and it didn't work.

The solution wound up being placing an if{} statement in the comments template, and then setting up two different layouts based upon the results.

Now it all works like it should.